# Catch if url is loaded or not

Tags: java, android, url, webview

I have a simple app that displays a webpage in a WebView. Because one of the url is not yet online I want to make a toast that says it isn't online and when it is, it just loads the url.

Does someone know a way of how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Open up a URLConnection, and check the response code of the connection first. If this is 404, it means the site does not exist. You could then do all your needed site-missing stuff there. Example code:

```
 try {
      Url url = new URL(someStringUrl);
      HttpURLConnection huc =  ( HttpURLConnection )  url.openConnection (); 
      if(huc.getResponseCode() == 404) {
           //Site doesnt exist, returned 404 error
      }
 } catch(Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: thanks it's almost the answer only i use a string as url so it is giving an error on "url.openconnection".

Comment: It wont work it just gives a blank page, i also have tried to make a toast. But there is nothing. Also when i try a page that is online at the moment it gives a blank page

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your own exception, lets say

```
public class Exception404 extends Exception {
}
```

and then catch 2 different exceptions:

```
HttpURLConnection huc = null;

try {
     Url url = new URL(someStringUrl);
     huc =  ( HttpURLConnection )  url.openConnection (); 
     if(huc.getResponseCode() == 404) 
        throw new Exception404();

     //...
     //...
     //...

 } catch(Exception404 e) { 
    e.printStackTrace();    
 } catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
    //close connection (saves battery life time)
    huc.disconnect();
 }
```

Or you could just throw the same exception handle both failures the same way

Comment: How is this any different than mine? They both have the exact same result, just mine's posted first...? If there is a major difference, just tell me, I could be missing something

Comment: Yes, you are right.However, throwing an exception, makes the code a bit more readable, because you handle the unexpected results at the end of the try block.Moreover, maybe there is need to throw 304 (unmodified since) which will not be handled by the following function, but by the function which called this function.This is more convinced than passing a boolean on success/failure

Comment: Moreover, I've closed the connection at the end of the try block which will turn of the radio of the android device (battery life time saving)

Comment: Throwing an exception there still isn't much more pretty or readable than if statements, or switch the response code. However, I did forget the diconnect ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well see this...

```
try {
      // Write your code to access the website here
```

} catch(Exception e) {

```
// Your execution will reach here once the site can't be reached

 Toast.makeText(Your_Activity.this, "Site still not online",duration).show();
```

}